# How do I find covariance and correlation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data sets saved in the csv file. Column names "avg" and "hu". I want to find the covariance and correlation values ​​of these two data sets. I tried it with some simple codes. But every time I got an error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    

data=pd.read_csv("80hucov.csv")
avg=data["avg"]
hu=data["hu"]
data = np.array(["avg, hu"])
covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
print (covMatrix)







    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data=pd.read_csv("80hucov.csv")


data = {'A': ["avg"],
        'B': ["hu"],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])

covMatrix = pd.DataFrame.cov(df)
sn.heatmap(covMatrix, annot=True, fmt='g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: please add an example of your dataset and the error message you are getting. This will help getting an answer.

Comment: Instead of `data = np.array(["avg, hu"])`, try `data = np.array([avg, hu])`. You are simply creating an array with a string, not with your data.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: first code says  KeyError: 'avg' and second ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation fmin which has no identity

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may need to redefine your definition of the array.
Currently you have:

```
data = np.array(["avg, hu"])
```

You can do:

```
data_array = data[['avg', 'hu']].to_numpy()
```

I recommend using different names for different objets within your code. In your example you use "data" for both your dataframe and your array.